# Running time of GCD Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time, asymptotic-complexity

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned int n, unsigned int m)
{
if (n == 0) 
    return m; 
if (m == 0) 
    return n; 

while (m! = n)
{
if (n > m) 
    n = n − m; 
else 
    m = m − n;
}
return n;
}
```

Some psuedocode for an iterative GCD algorithm using a while loop. I there are no places where there is anything being divided by 2, so I do not think that it is logarithmic. Since the while loop runs for a time directly proportional to N does it make it linear like O(N)?

Comment: This appears to be a broken implementation of the binary GCD algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm   When implemented properly it's O(log (m+n)), but this one is O(m+n)

Comment: @MattTimmermans It doesn't strike me as broken so much as deliberately inefficient so as to make a homework questions in an algorithms class.

Comment: @MattTimmermans It's O(m+n), but that's not a tight bound. O((m+n)/gcd(m, n)) is a better bound, but I don't think that's tight either.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is `O(max(n,m))` because it big-O should be symmetric for n vs m since the algorithm is.
@PaulHankin improves this to be `O(max(n,m)/gcd(n,m))`.

Comment: Why does O(max(n, m)) follow from the symmetry of the function? It's certainly not a tight bound since for example gcd(n, kn) runs in O(k) time, and not O(kn). O(max(n, m)/gcd(n, m)) is a better try, but it's also not tight.

Comment: Yeah, O(max(n,m)/gcd(n,m)) is nice. Why do you think it is not tight?  I didn't mean to say that O(max(n,m)) follows from symmetry, I meant to say that since algorithm is symmetrical for n and m, so O should be also symmetrical.

Comment: It's not tight because for example gcd(fib(n), fib(n+1)) runs in O(n) time, but gcd(fib(n), fib(n+1))=1 and fib(n+1) is exponentially bigger than n. (Here fib(k) = kth fibonacci number).